# Powershell - txt file search

Tags: powershell, search, config, ini

**Im currently trying to get a script to do the following:**

*search a file location and obtain any .txt,.ini,.config file.
filter this file on an input from the user.
move all the files to a location.*

Im having a problem trying to feed in the variable and its probably really simple but im currently struggling to figure out what I need to do without splitting the string up manually. any ideas?

```
$QQ = Read-Host -Prompt "String your searching for:"
$QL = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the file location you wish to search:"
$FT = Get-ChildItem -Path "$QL" -recurse | where {$_.extension -eq ".txt"} | %  {$_.fullname}
$FI = Get-ChildItem -Path "$QL" -recurse | where {$_.extension -eq ".ini"} | %  {$_.fullname}
$FC = Get-ChildItem -Path "$QL" -recurse | where {$_.extension -eq ".config"} | %  {$_.fullname}
$FTS = Get-Content -Path "$FT" -Filter "$QQ" 
$FIS = Get-Content -Path "$FI" -Filter "$QQ"
$FCS = Get-Content -Path "$FC" -Filter "$QQ"
$FD = "C:\Search-$QQ"
$FD1 = Get-ChildItem $FD

function folder {
    if ($FD -eq $Null) {New-Item "$FD" -ItemType directory}}

function search{
    if ($FTS -ne $null){Copy-Item -Path $ft -Destination "$fd"  | Write-Host "$FT" | Format-List}
    if ($FIS -ne $null){Copy-Item -path $fi -Destination "$fd" | Write-Host "$FI" | Format-List}
    if ($FCS -ne $null){Copy-Item -Path $fc -destination "$fd" | Write-Host "$FC" | Format-List}
}
folder
search;
```

**An example of the error being received is**: *(obviously an issue with it treating the multiple files in the string as one)*

Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\test\Test\1c.config C:\test\Test\2c.config C:\test\Test\3c.config' because it does not exist.

Comment: Ive fixed it myselfjust needed to drop the quotes off the $FT,$FI,$FC on the $FTS,$FIS,$FCS variables.

Answer (score 1):

right off the bat I see the `folder` function will not work property as `$FD` will never be null since you assign a string to it, if you need to check if the folder exists use `Test-Path`.  but in relation to your actual script the problem is your use of `get-content` which is trying to read all of your files contents into an array of strings.  from the looks of it you should just be working with the arrays returned by `Get-ChildItem` and use `Test-Path` to check your paths rather than that weird `Get-Content` method you are using(since the content of the files doesn't matter, just whether they exist or not).  You also need to incorporate a loop to act on each array element individually rather than trying to work on them in groups like you are.

Comment: Fair point about the test-path. I do however care about the contents of the file hence trying to filter on the content.

Comment: Ive fixed it anyway just needed to drop the quotes off the $FT,$FI,$FC on the $FTS,$FIS,$FCS variables.

Answer (score 0):

(This Script is to mass search application files to find values like server id's or passwords hardcoded etc)

Fixed code:

```
$QQ = Read-Host -Prompt "String your searching for:"
$QL = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the file location you wish to search:"
$FT = Get-ChildItem -Path "$QL" -recurse | where {$_.extension -eq ".txt"} | %  {$_.fullname}
$FI = Get-ChildItem -Path "$QL" -recurse | where {$_.extension -eq ".ini"} | %  {$_.fullname}
$FC = Get-ChildItem -Path "$QL" -recurse | where {$_.extension -eq ".config"} | %  {$_.fullname}
$FTS = Get-Content -Path $FT -Filter "$QQ" 
$FIS = Get-Content -Path $FI -Filter "$QQ"
$FCS = Get-Content -Path $FC -Filter "$QQ"
$FD = "C:\Support\Search-$QQ"
$FD1 = Test-Path $FD

function folder {
if ($FD1 -eq $false) {New-Item "$FD" -ItemType directory}
}
function search{
    if ($FTS -ne $null){Copy-Item -Path $ft -Destination "$fd"  | Write-Host "$FT" | Format-List}
    if ($FIS -ne $null){Copy-Item -path $fi -Destination "$fd" | Write-Host "$FI" | Format-List}
    if ($FCS -ne $null){Copy-Item -Path $fc -destination "$fd" | Write-Host "$FC" | Format-List}
}

folder
search;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$QL = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the file location you wish to search:"
if (-not (Test-Path $QL))
{
  write-host "Specified path ($QL) doesnt exists "  
  return;
}

$QQ = Read-Host -Prompt "String your searching for:"
$FD = "C:\Search-$QQ"
New-Item "C:\Search-$QQ" -ItemType directory -Force | out-null

Get-ChildItem -Path "$QL" -recurse -include "*.txt", "*.ini", "*.config" | 
    select-string -Pattern "$QQ" -SimpleMatch | 
        %{ Copy-Item -Path $_.Path -Destination "$fd" -Force ; $_.Path }
```